# How is $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{(\frac{-x_i}{r}+r)}{r²} =\frac1r$ where r is |x|

Tags: analysis, derivatives

I just cannot find the way to show this :( [image]

It happens after the 5th equality sign.

So my question is in line 4 how $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(\frac{-x_i}{r}+r)}{r²} =\frac1r$

Comment: Please do not use pictures in your question, rather use LaTeX or MathJax syntax to write your question. Also be more clear about what your problem is.

Comment: There is a mistake from the third to fourth line: $\partial x_i\left(\frac{x_i}{r}\right) = \frac{r-\frac{x_i^2}{r}}{r^2}$, not $\frac{r-\frac{x_i}{r}}{r^2}$. Hopefully the result should be clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly as @Joey said, there is a mistake in the partial derivative. It should read
$$\partial_{x_i}\left(\frac{x_i}{r}\right)=\frac{r-\frac{x_i^2}{r}}{r^2},$$
now using that 
$$x_1^2+x_2^2=r^2,$$
one has that
$$\sum_{i=1}^2\frac{r-\frac{x_2^2}{r}}{r^2}=\frac{2r-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^2x_2^2}{r}}{r^2}=\frac{2r-\frac{r^2}{r}}{r^2}=\frac{1}{r}.$$

Comment: Thanks you for pointing out the mistake. If I see this right, Is the Numerator n-1 for general n?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.